Programatically change layout builder entity view display
I have a content type article with default display and layout builder configured for that display. I have created a second view display for that content type and configured the layout builder with totally different settings for that type also.
What I want to do is to change layout builder to use this new display, not the default one based on some conditions. What is the best way to achieve that ?
I tried using
hook_entity_view_display_alter but the layout builder has the default blocks and it does not work.
Thanks for help.

Layout Builder stores its values as config, so one way to do this is a find-and-replace on the relevant config entries.
